# Redirect when Edit a Kendo UI grid with ASP .NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to add a redirection to another page when I click on the "Edit" button with a Kendo UI grid with ASP .NET MVC.

Here is the base code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ViewModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(x => x.Id);
        columns.Bound(x => x.Name);
        columns.Bound(x => x.Field1);
        columns.Command(commands =>
        {
            commands.Edit();
            commands.Destroy();
        })
    })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Model(model => model.Id(x => x.Id))
        .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Home"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("Edit", "Home"))
        .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Destroy", "Home"))
    )
)
```

I tried to use the HTML attributes but it doesn't work:

```
commands.Edit().HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "edit" });
```

Then, I tried to add a custom edit (via commands.Custom(...) but unfortunately it is just for .Server() data binding.

I can do it with a client template but I really would like to use the default button proposed by Kendo UI:

```
columns.Template(@<text></text>)
            .ClientTemplate(
                "<a href='" + Url.Action("Edit", "Home") + "/#=Id#'>Edit</a>");
```

Do you have any other idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to use custom commands, even with an Ajax datasource. I just tested this locally with the following code to make sure it will still work.

Code from view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function redirectTest(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
        alert(dataItem.Name);
    }
</script>

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ViewModel>()
.Name("testing")
.Columns(columns => 
    {
      columns.Bound(x => x.Id);
      columns.Bound(x => x.Name);
      columns.Command(command => command.Custom("Edit").Click("redirectTest"));
    })
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Read(read => read.Action("ReadAction", "ControllerName"))
)
)
```

Source: [Custom command demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/custom-command.html)

Comment: You're right, it actually works! I don't remember why I had an error but whatever. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect to another page with accepts a parameter then use this method.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<AGridViewModel>()
  .Name("Grid")
  .Columns(columns => {
    columns.Bound(p => p.Id)
    columns.Bound(p => p.Name);
    columns.Command(command => command.Custom("View Details").Click("showDetails"));

})

<script type="text/javascript">  
function showDetails(e) {  
    e.preventDefault();
    var d = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
    //alert("Selected item ID is:" + d.Id);
    window.location.href = "@Url.Action("action", "controller")?id=" + d.Id;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a custom ClientTemplate on the Name column, instead, and remove your `columns.Command` button altogether, where they simply click the name to edit it, and you pass in your object's ID to the new page like this:

```
columns.Bound(x => x.Name).ClientTemplate("<a href=/SomeViewFolder/Index?id=${id} target=_blank>${Name}</a>");
```

Comment: If you have few commands adding such template without migrating all to bound column causes your commands buttons split across two or more columns which is not that cool

Comment: OP used bound columns, so that was my assumption someone would be using, here. I would think to do create, read, update, delete, the columns would, more often than not, be bound. I'd say other instances are a little more cutting edge and so those people should probably know what they are doing, already.